# Pulumi RemoteImage Authentication Fails with Google Artifact Registry

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, pulumi

There are a few layers of problems I'm encountering.

I'm using pulumi to build out Google App Engine using the Flexible App model. I specify the tag for the container to use for each service in my pulumi config. However, pulumi resolves the tag to a digest and stores that in the pulumi stack state. Future deployments compare the image with a digest (state) to an image with a tag (code) which causes a redeploy of the service.

```
  const appVersion = new gcp.appengine.FlexibleAppVersion(`service`, {
    project: "my-project",
    versionId: "service-version",
    service: "default",
    runtime: "custom",
    deployment: {
      container: {
        image: "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/docker/service:0.0.1"
      },
    },
  })
```

Is there a way to store the container image state using the provided tag instead of the digest?

My attempted workaround is to pull the image using pulumi's `docker.RemoteImage` based on tag so that I can provide a digest for the image to the `FlexibleAppVersion`.

```
  const appImage = new docker.RemoteImage("appImage", {
    name: "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/docker/service:0.0.1",
  })

  const appVersion = new gcp.appengine.FlexibleAppVersion(`service`, {
    project: "my-project",
    versionId: "service-version",
    service: "default",
    runtime: "custom",
    deployment: {
      container: {
        image: appImage.repoDigest
      },
    },
  })
```

The problem I encounter here is that pulumi is not able to pull the image from the private repository, however I am able to pull it using docker directly.

```
Unable to read Docker image into resource: unable to pull image us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/docker/service:0.0.1: error pulling image us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/docker/service:0.0.1: Error response from daemon: Head "https://us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/v2/my-project/docker/service/manifests/0.0.1": denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied on resource "projects/my-project/locations/us-central1/repositories/docker" (or it may not exist)
```

However, running `docker pull us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/docker/service:0.0.1` in the same terminal where I run `pulumi up` is successful.

To login to gcloud I've run the following:

```
> gcloud auth application-default login
> gcloud auth configure-docker us-central1-docker.pkg.dev
```

It seems that `new docker.RemoteImage` is not using the authentication from my machine when attempting to pull the image. Is there a way to force pulumi to act using the same credentials the docker command line is using?